# SQL STATE Error while setup:upgrade in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, database, xampp

[image]

Getting this error when adding the new module, i don't have this table in database but i am getting this error, anyone can help?

Comment: can you post your installSchema or UpgradeSchema

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bypass this error by checking first in your script if the table exists or not.
Something like this:

```
$tableName = $installer->getTable('yourTableName');

if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
  //your create table script
}
```